# Js how to write multiple ifs in a efficient way?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nested

I am still a beginner to JS and I am kinda struggling on how to write multiple ifs in a correct way. For example I wrote something like this:

```js
function calculatespot() {
  //Spot 1 to 2 transfer bandage
  if (spot1Selected == 1 && spot2Selected == 1) {
    if (spot2Free == 1) {
      localStorage.setItem('spot1Free', 1)
      localStorage.setItem('spot2Free', 0)
      localStorage.setItem('spot1Selected', 0)
      localStorage.setItem('spot2Selected', 0)
      document.getElementById('block1').style.backgroundColor = "#9eafa6"
      document.getElementById('block2').style.backgroundColor = "#9eafa6"
      if (user_item1 == "Bandage") {
        localStorage.setItem("slot1Type", "")
        localStorage.setItem("slot2Type", "Bandage")
        document.getElementById('inventoryactionbtn').style.visibility = "Hidden"
        document.getElementById('item1').src = "/static/images/transparant.png"
        document.getElementById('item2').src = "/static/images/bandage.png"
        localStorage.setItem('slot1Type', "")
        localStorage.setItem('slot2Type', "Bandage")
      }
    }
  }
```

This is not a very good way, but I still need all those points to match before executing the code. How could I write something like this in a better and more efficient way without having to nest all those ifs?

Comment: _"This is not a very good way"_ - Why? The only problem I see are the missing semicolons.

Comment: Move `spot2Free == 1` also to main if condition. But everything else is quite good and I don't think you have what to improve, especially since you do not provide _any_ logic explanation

Comment: Because to me if there are to many ifs it becomes a big mess and hard to read.

Comment: It is quite readable. What bothers me more is to see you have HTML with id attributes like "item1", "item2", ... etc. That is not best practice.

Comment: Can you have more then two checks in the main condition then like this: if (spot1Selected == 1 && spot2Selected == 1 &&  spot2Free == 1) {  @Justinas

Comment: @trincot How would you recommend replacing those?

Comment: @SpringerJerry Yes, you can have as much as you want, there is no limit in how much conditions there can be

Comment: Concerning HTML id attributes, this would be a different question, and it depends on what the larger goal is you have here. But generally it is better to enumerate multiple items not by adding a numerical suffix, but to use class attributes instead, and use the same class for items that are similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think about the following things to do:

- reverse logic and return
- separate logic in multiple functions

That will look like this. Which has the same functionality as your code, but less nested:

```
function setToSpot2Free() {
  localStorage.setItem('spot1Free', 1)
  localStorage.setItem('spot2Free', 0)
  localStorage.setItem('spot1Selected', 0)
  localStorage.setItem('spot2Selected', 0)
  document.getElementById('block1').style.backgroundColor = "#9eafa6"
  document.getElementById('block2').style.backgroundColor = "#9eafa6"
}

function setType2(type) {
  localStorage.setItem("slot1Type", "")
  localStorage.setItem("slot2Type", type)
  document.getElementById('inventoryactionbtn').style.visibility = "Hidden" 
  document.getElementById('item1').src = "/static/images/transparant.png"  
  document.getElementById('item2').src = `/static/images/${type.toLowerCase()}.png`
}

function calculatespot() {
  if (spot1Selected !== 1 || spot2Selected !== 1 || spot2Free !== 1) {
    return;
  }

  setToSpot2Free();

  if (user_item == 'Bandage') {
    setType2(user_item);
  }
}
```

Obviously there are more things iffy with your code, but you'll get there :)

A very important concept, at least to me, is the DRY principle. Which means, "Don't repeat yourself". If you are noticing that you are doing the same thing twice, with only a small difference in code, you can probably move this logic in its own function and set the "small difference(s)" as parameter(s) of that function.